# woo commerce single product page banner image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a banner image on my single product page woo-commerce. I want to use Advanced Custom Field plugin for this, so user can change the banner on each product. I want this banner after the product description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' filter.You need to create a function in "function.php'
You can try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'banner_image',28 );
function banner_image()
{
    if(get_field('product_banner'))
    {
        echo '<img src="'.get_field("product_banner").'" alt="banner product" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for solving my problem